# Change Detection

Tags: security, configuration-management, sysadmin

I am currently using TDI Console Works for baseline and configuration change detection, and it is, unfortunately, rather expensive software. I was hoping someone might be able to recommend an alternative that would serve the narrow use case I am using Console Works for.

Essentially, I just need something that can communicate with a device over SSH or telnet, run some commands I give it (such as "show run" for a Cisco switch), save those results as a baseline, and then continuously run that same command to see if the config has changed (basically just run a diff). If so, send some sort of alert and a syslog message to a graylog server.

Anyone have any recommendations? Preferable open source, but that is not mandatory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this with `cron` or `anacron`, an SSH client, `diff`, and whatever program you want to use to send an alert. Use an (ana)cron job to periodically run a command like `ssh user@server 'do-stuff && do-more-stuff' >/tmp/new-results; if ! diff -q /tmp/new-results saved-results; then alert-program "The results have changed"; fi`.